# Problems building fastdroid-vnc on Android ICS x86

Tags: android, makefile, vnc

I managed to build Android ICS full_eng_x86. Now I'd like to add [fastdroid-vnc](https://code.google.com/p/fastdroid-vnc/)  to the build.

What I did:

1. Checked out the code via SVN
2. Copied the folder to external/fastdroid-vnc
3. make clean
4. make -j4

Now I get the following error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target     `out/target/product/generic_x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libjpeg_intermediates/export_includes', needed by `out/target/product/generic_x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/fastdroid-vnc_intermediates/import_includes'.  Stop.
```

Does anyone know how to build this? I get a similar error message when I try to build for ARM.

Answer (score 1):

It works now. The trick was to modify Android.mk and add libjpeg as a shared library (instead of a static one).